# Residue of a complex function with essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the residue of the function:
$$
\frac{e^{1/z}}{1-z}
$$

when $z_0 = 0$

I don't know how to proceed with this exercise. I can't find the Laurent Series of the function around $z_0 = 0$. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ centered in $0$ can be found easily using the exponential series; on the other hand, $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is the sum of a geometric series. Therefore the Laurent series of your function is the *Cauchy product* of the series of $e^{1/z}$ and $\frac{1}{1-z}$. Of course, you are only interested in the coefficient $c_{-1}$ of the power $1/z$ of the Cauchy product...

Comment: @Somos, sorry, but I can't understand what you mean. The function $e^{1/z}$ doesn't have a Laurent expansion at $0$ because of the essential singularity?

Comment: @Pacciu I was confused. The Wikipedia article [Laurent  series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) gives $e^{-1/z^2}$ as an example. Notice they did not use $e^{1/z^2}$ as an example. I wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

$$\begin{split} e^{1/z} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\ z^{-n} \\ \frac{1}{1 - z} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \end{split}$$

hence you can write:

$$\begin{split} e^{1/z} &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\ z^n \\ \frac{1}{1 - z} &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n \end{split}$$

where:

$$\begin{split} a_n &= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{(-n)!} &\text{, if } n\leq 0 \\ 0 &\text{, if } n>0 \end{cases} \\ b_n &= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{, se } n<0 \\ 1 &\text{, if } n \geq 0 \end{cases} \end{split}\; .$$

Therefore the Laurent series of your function is given by:

$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{1 - z} = \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\ z^n \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \underbrace{\left( \sum_{h+k=n} a_hb_k \right)}_{=:c_n}\ z^n\; .$$

Now, you're interested only in $c_{-1} = \operatorname{Res}(f;0)$ and this coefficient evaluates into:

$$\begin{split} c_{-1} &= \sum_{h+k=-1} a_hb_k \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{-1-k} b_k \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\ &\stackrel{i=k+1}{=} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!} \\ &= e-1\; .\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: could you explain how to obtain k + 1 = i ?

Comment: It is just an index shift to make the series more similar to $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}$.